# Java "The label Label244 is missing" error

Tags: java, eclipse

I see this error in the error list but can't seem to find a fix for it. Everything I try doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
  if (this.mouseX >= 522 + paddingX + (clientSize >= 1 ? 3 - (this.longTabs ? 240 : 0) : 0)) {
    if (this.mouseX <= 762 + paddingX + (clientSize >= 1 ? 3 - (this.longTabs ? 240 : 0) : 0)) {
      if (this.mouseY >= '©' + (clientSize >= 1 ? 261 + (this.longTabs ? 37 : 0) : 0) + paddingY) {
        if (this.mouseY < '�' + (clientSize >= 1 ? 261 + (this.longTabs ? 37 : 0) : 0) + paddingY) {
          break label244; } //Where the error is
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But the label244 is set here:

```
        {
          int i;
          label244: i = 0;
          for (int x = 0; i < 8; x += 30)
          {
```

Could I be told how to fix these with some examples please? I have 17 of these errors remaining.

Comment: Is your `if` inside `for (int x = 0; i < 8; x += 30)` loop?

Comment: My `if` is in another `if` statement, which is just under `private void processesTabClick(int paddingX, int paddingY)`

Comment: Are you trying to say that your `if` is in entirely different method than method containing `for` loop? I am asking since having such `if` before `for loop` in same method wouldn't have any sense because loop wouldn't even start iterating when condition of `if` would be checked.

Comment: BTW if you are writing comment to someone write also `@nick` of that person. This way person with that `nick` will be notified about your comment. So if you want to answer my comment use `@pshemo your response`.

Answer (score 1):

From [Java Language Specification #14.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) (emphasis mine)

> [...] Java programming language has no `goto` statement; identifier statement labels are used with `break` (§14.15) or `continue` (§14.16) statements **appearing anywhere within the labeled statement**.
>
> The **scope of a label of a labeled statement is the immediately contained *Statement***.

Which means that label

```
label244: i = 0;
```

is affecting only `i=0`. In other words it is similar to

```
label244: {
    //here you can use label
    i = 0;
}
//but here label is no longer accessible.
```

so it is not visible/accessible outside of this scope.

If you want to use it inside `for` scope then place it right before it (move it after `i = 0;`).

```
int i;
i = 0;
label244: 
for (int x = 0; i < 8; x += 30)
{
    //...
}
```